# How to get individual count using this MySql Query

Tags: mysql, count

I have table and this table contain `result column` with some entries. I just wanted to know how to get individual count these entries using MySql Query like this (*see result required*)...
also
(*see the result column image and query*) or helps are definitely appreciated

**Result Column Image**

[image]

**Query**

```
SELECT cpd.result FROM cron_players_data cpd
WHERE cpd.`status` = '1' 
AND (cpd.`result` = '1' OR cpd.`result` = '2') 
AND cpd.`player_id` = '81'
```

**Result Required**

```
result count
1      2
2      6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cpd.result, count(*) FROM cron_players_data cpd
WHERE cpd.`status` = '1' 
AND (cpd.`result` = '1' OR cpd.`result` = '2') 
AND cpd.`player_id` = '81' group by cpd.`result`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT result, COUNT(result) `count` FROM
(
    SELECT cpd.result result 
    FROM cron_players_data cpd
    WHERE cpd.`status` = '1' 
        AND (cpd.`result` = '1' OR cpd.`result` = '2') 
        AND cpd.`player_id` = '81'
) a
GROUP BY result
```